# Получить список коммитов для определённой папки

Tags: git

> Внимание! Это перевод вопроса [How to show git log history for a sub
>   directory of a git
>   repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16343659/5752652)

Предположим что у меня есть git-репозиторий, который выглядит примерно так:

```
foo/
  .git/
  A/
   ... большое число (под)папок
  B/
   ... большое число (под)папок
```

Есть ли способ получить список коммитов для определённой директории? Например, я хочу посмотреть коммиты относящиеся только к папке `foo/A`.

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16343659/5752652

Answer (score 1):

Находясь в директории `foo/`, дайте команду

```
  git log -- A
```

Это покажет вам только коммиты, относящиеся к папке `foo/А`

Также вы можете указывать несколько папок:

```
  git log -- A B
```

Указание пути лучше отделять от указания `<since>..<until>` при помощи '--', например:

```
$ git log --oneline -- src/nvfs
d6f6b3b Changes for Mac OS X
803fcc3 Initial Commit

$ git log --oneline 803fcc3 -- src/nvfs
803fcc3 Initial Commit

$ git log --oneline
d6f6b3b Changes for Mac OS X
96cbb79 gitignore
803fcc3 Initial Commit
```