# Объединение репозиториев с сохранением коммитов

Tags: git

У меня в папке C:\temp\ валяется около сотни проектов visual studio, один проект - одна папка:

```
C:\temp\TestApp01\
...
C:\temp\WcfTest01\
```

и так далее.

И часть из этих проектов я решил влить в некий единый репозиторий c:\git\StudyProjects:

```
C:\git\StudyProjects\TestApp01\
...
C:\git\StudyProjects\WcfTest01\
```

Причём не просто перелить, а желательно с сохранением коммитов. Мне необязательно, чтобы каждый из них был датирован реальной датой коммита, они могут быть датированы сегодняшней датой, мне критично, чтобы вливая проект сохранилось число и порядок коммитов, чтобы я потом мог [посмотреть фильтруя по папке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/906967/213987) историю коммитов.

Как это сделать? Очень не хочется ручками переносить, хочется автоматизировать: указал имя исходного проекта, указал в какой проект вливать. Но чтобы такой скрипт написать - нужно понимать, какими вообще командами это можно сделать.

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной задачей?

Comment: Ага, называется subtree merging https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Subtree-Merging

Comment: Там будут два дерева (корня) коммитов просто, потом они сойдутся в мерж-коммите и дальше нормальное дерево.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, есть и [по-русски](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%8C%D0%B5%D0%B2), но ни там ни там не описан и даже не упомянут [скрипт subtree](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.sh), который вы, вероятно, и подразумевали.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin да, я имел в виду именно его, спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно воспользоваться [скриптом `subtree`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.sh), входящим в «комплект», устанавливаемый вместе с программой *git*:

```
$ git subtree add -P подкаталог url-хранилища ветка-в-нём
```

после выполнения этой команды:

1. из указанного удалённого хранилища будет получена указанная ветка
2. её коммиты будут объединены (*merged*) с коммитами в текущей ветке текущего хранилища
3. файлы/каталоги из этой влитой ветки будут помещены в указанный `подкаталог`

---

подробное описание: [`$ man git-subtree`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.txt)